# Display the value of an Entity Framework model's ErrorMessage in the view HTML

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I've got an EF CORE model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the surname")]
public string Surname { get; set; }
```

and I'd like to know how to access the `ErrorMessage` text in the view.
I can change the default text using

```
<input asp-for="myRecord.Surname" class="form-control" required  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter the surname')" />
```

but this means putting the ErrorMessage text in twice and I wondered if it's possible to use what text is in the model directly.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to achieve. Are you simply trying to display the error message? If so you can do something like `<span asp-validation-for="myRecord.Surname" class="text-danger"></span>`

Comment: That's the scaffolded HTML span. I'm trying to get the ErrorMessage into the JavaScript. The span works and appears but I need to pop up a JavaScript tooltip, the code I've got does that, but I have to type "Please enter the surname" twice in two places so want to access the ErrorMessage value from the model directly.